# Performing a custom query inside Doctrine entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity (B) which is responsible for managing custom templates. Upon updating entity A I need to query entity B to fetch the desired template and do the necessary processing.

Something like:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Bundle\EmailsBundle\Entity\Email;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class MemberApplication extends EntityRepository
{

    public function sendUpdateNotificationEmails()
    {
        // Send email to user
        $emailRow = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT * FROM emails where `type` = 'x' LIMIT 1")
            ->getResult();        
    }


    (...)
}
```

This returns me an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function createQuery() on a non-object in Classpath/Classname.php
```

Both $this->getEntityManager() and $this->_em is NULL.

I read a similar approach in http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes and I'm unable to figure out why this isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: are you not loading the entity? use Bundle\Whatever\Entity\EntityName;

Comment: I am now. Still the output is the same. Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this->getEntityManager() returns null because the dependence on doctrine is not injected. Try $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); instead. This should be done in the controller side though so something like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$memberRepo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MemberApplication');
$result = $memberRepo->sendUpdateNotificationEmails();
```

then in your function you should return $emailRow or what you want.

Comment: The problem with doing this on the controller is that I'm using Sonata admin as well as this would make me to repeat code. Wanted to avoid that but I guess it's the right way to do it really